# Delaying hover effect for menu

Tags: html, css

I want to use this style

[image]

[Site](http://liquidwinter.com/resources/style) > Then choose the Zerus theme.

The CSS for Zerus is as follows:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600');

/* Fonts */
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, #content a, ul.lw-hmenu a, .lw-hmenu li span.nav-header, #lw-topnav ul a, #lw-topnav ul li span.nav-header {
    font-weight: 600;
}

#content a::after {
    content: "→";
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#content div.pagination ul li a::after {
    content: "";
    padding-left: 0;
}
/* End Fonts */

/* Colors */
:root{
  --primary: #24b47e;
  --accent: #6772e5;
  --accent2: #b76ac4;
  --ux: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  --ux-border: #6b7c93;
}

.lw_svg_logo {
    fill: var(--primary);
}

#masterPage {
    background-color:#F6F9FC;
}

#contentPage {
    background-color: #F6F9FC;
}

body {
    color:#6b7c93;
}

a, span.nav-header {
    color: var(--accent);
}
/* End Colors */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #lw-topnav {
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        border-bottom: 9px solid var(--ux-border);
    }

    #lw-topnav ul>li:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    }

    #lw-topnav ul li ul {
        border-radius: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        margin-top:15px !important;
    }

    #lw-topnav ul li ul::before {
        display:block;
        content: "";
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        background-color: var(--ux);
        position:relative;
        left:50%;
        margin-top:5px;
        transform: translateX(-50%) rotateZ(45deg);
        z-index:1;
        top:-15px;
    }

    #lw-topnav ul li ul::after {
        display:block;
        content: "";
        height:9px;
        background-color: var(--ux-border);
        z-index:1;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    }   

    #lw-topnav ul li ul li ul {
        border-radius: 8px;
        margin-top: 0px !important;
    }

    #lw-topnav ul li ul li ul::before {
        display:none;
    }

    #lw-topnav ul>li:hover:after{
        content:"";
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        top:0px;
        height:120%;
        z-index:-1;
    }
}
```

I would like to lower the menu that appears when you hover over the top navigation by about 15px. If I do however, then I can't actually get to the sub-menu because the mouse leaves the `<li>` that contains the hover effect to make it visible, so the menu disappears.

You can see the effect I want by adding this:

```
#lw-topnav ul li ul {
    margin-top:15px !important;
}
```

I think this can be achieved by using a `transition-delay`, but no matter where I put it, it doesn't seem to have any effect. I'd like to avoid using javascript if I have to. Can anyone help on where to add the transition-delay?

Thanks

Comment: Links to sites to explain the problem are not good: In the future, once you change the site (or it goes away), this question has no value.  Include the relevant bits you need to recreate the issue into your question.

Comment: If you are referring to the submenu "colors" then I am not sure what the issue is. I can hover over that submenu fine without it disappearing.

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as accepted instead of editing question title

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is, that your mouse leaves the `<li>` of the top list, so the hover-event is not working anymore. You have to seperate the display of the sublist and the area where the list item is considered as "hovered".

These are two things, while you see the list itself, you cannot see the area where the program accepts the item as "hovered".

I created a little example by copying and modifying code from [SelfHTML](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Anwendung_und_Praxis/Dropdown-Men%C3%BCs_mit_CSS_gestalten) where I point out the problem you face.
If you modify the values I highlighted you see the difference.

```
<html>  
<head>
<style>
nav {
border: 1px solid black;
height: 2em;
padding: 0.8em;
width: 50em;
}

nav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}

nav li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
}

/* important here */

nav ul ul {
font: 0/0 serif;
margin-top: 40px;  /*this changes the display of the sublist*/
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0em;
/*change this to shift the space where your cursor stays with the sublist*/
z-index: -1;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
font: inherit;
z-index: auto;
color: red;
}

nav ul ul li {
float: none;
margin-bottom: 0.2em;
}

nav a,
nav span {
background-color: royalblue;
border: 1px solid blue;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px white inset;
color: gold;
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0.6em 0 0 0;
padding: 0.4em;
width: 6.4em;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

nav ul ul a,
nav ul ul span {
border-radius: 10px;
}

nav a:focus,
nav a:hover,
nav span
 {
color: royalblue;
background-color: gold;
}

nav a:focus,
nav a:hover {
margin-top: 0;
padding: 1em 0.4em 0.4em;
}

nav ul ul a:hover {
margin: 0.6em 0 0 0;
padding: 0.4em;
}

nav ul ul span {
background-color: maroon;
color: gold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>  
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Seite 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Seite 2</a>
       <ul> 
            <li><a href="#">Seite 2a</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Seite 2b</a></li>

       </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Seite 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Seite 4</a>
       <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Seite 4a</a></li>
            <li><span>aktuelle Seite</span></li>            
            <li><a href="#">Seite 4c</a></li>   
       </ul>            
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Seite 5</a></li>
</ul>   
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure that your mouse is always hovering the selected list item by modifying the `top:0em` to 0 or even below 0. To balance the fact that your menu will move upward, simply adjust the `margin-top` in the same frame! This all has to happen in the sublist itself `nav ul ul` and of course with another level of depth if you create a list like that! :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding an invisible div behind it.

```
#lw-topnav ul>li:hover:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0px;
    height:120%;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

That being said.  I think S.M.'s solution is better.  I'll play around with it more.